# How do I append a text file?

Tags: python, append

More precisely: what is the "directory" or "section" of a text file?

This code is not working:

```
file_path = os.path.abspath(Input_File_Path)
text_path = 'texts'
text_name = 'Sample_Text'

bpy.ops.wm.append(
   filepath=os.path.join(file_path, text_path, text_name),
   directory=os.path.join(file_path, text_path),
   filename=text_name
)
```

I guess the problem lies at the `text_path`.

When in Blender I look for `bpy.data.texts['Sample_Text'].filepath`, I get `''` although the text exists.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It helps if you post the error Traceback if you want help debugging the error.

Comment: That is the funny thing: no Error but also no appended text. I can append the text from the specified file via Blender interactively but I'm not able to do the same with python.

Comment: `wm.append` is meant for copying data blocks from one blender file to another.  (It's the implementation of the append menu entry).  If that's what you want, then `text_path` should be set to "Text" (no s, upper case T) and `text_name` to the name of the text block in the input file.  Is that what you want here?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I tested different Text_path entries (also 'text') but without the upper case T. With 'Text' it works perfectly. I could not find any reference on this so maybe it would be helpful if you could post this as the Answer.

Comment: Done.  I don't know of a part of the manual that explains this either.

Comment: FYI you need to go to *Help > Toggle System Console* to see the Python Traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wm.append`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.append) is meant for copying data blocks from one blender file to another. It is the implementation of the append menu entry.

You can determine how the *directory* entry you want is spelled by trying an append manually (*File* → *Append*); navigating to a Blend file and looking at what the file browser shows at that point, for example:

[image: File Browser navigated to a Blend file showing the directories.]

You can also determine this in the outliner by selecting *Blender File* as the display mode, but this approach has two exceptions:

- The names are all spelled as plurals, but as you can see in the above screenshot they're singular as "directories"
- A directory type will only be present if you have objects of that type in the *current* blend file.

In your case `text_path` should be set to "Text" (no s, upper case T) and `text_name` to the name of the text block in the input file.

Note that names are case sensitive.